# Java static methods/fields in interface (again!)

Tags: java, interface, static, overriding

my problem is:

- I have a bunch of different classes all extending a base class (`Identifiable`).
- I need to assign to *some* of the sub-class a certain value (`securityLevel`) which should be changeable and assigned to all member of the class (i.e.: it should be `static`).
- I need to access the classes via the common ancestor.
- How do I do this?

The first thing which came to mind is to have a dedicated `interface` (`ISecurity`) defining either the values or a static method to access them and let the actual classes either not to `implements` it and, if they do, to override the `static` field (or method to retrieve it).
However this is not possible for two reasons:

1. The current Java language does not allow `static` members in `interface`s.
2. Even if it would allow it it would not be possible to `@Override` it.

How can I code around the problem?
The only way I found is:

- add a non-`static` member (`public Class getValueProvider()`) to base class to retrieve the value returning `null`.
- in the interested classes `@Override` the non-`static` method returning the value of a `private static Class getValueProvider()` implementing setters and getters for the wanted value.
- use the retrieved `class` instance to obtain the requested value (or skip everything if the return is null).

This is very ugly and there's no way to enforce the correct implementation in sub-classes.

Comment: Have you looked into a (partially) abstract class? A few changes may need to be made but it could be nicer.

Comment: Actually your "ugly" solution was what came to mind when reading your question. How about showing us some client code, so we can better understand what you want looking nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a service/factory type of implementation.  Or have some sort of class object that stores security (`SecuritySettings`) and send in the current `Identifiable` object to get security level

```
    public class Identifiable { }
    public class SampleUser extends Identifiable { }
    public class ExampleUser extends Identifiable { }

    public class UserService
    {
        public int SampleUserSecurity = 0;
        //Or an array/dictionary structure

        public int GetSecurityLevel(Identifiable user)
        {
            if(user instanceof SampleUser)
            {
                return SampleUserSecurity;
            }
        }

        public SampleUser CreateSampleUser()
        {
            return new SampleUser();
        }

        public ExampleUser CreateExampleUser()
        {
            return new ExampleUser();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a variation on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `Identifiable` to be an `abstract class`.  Additionally, you can define another `abstract class` that extends `Identifiable` and adheres to your restrictions, ie holds the `static variable` and whatever methods may be necessary.

Comment: I already thought of that; unfortunately Identifiable is an automatically generated class and I can only add something at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid any static members. Static members in java are always clamsy (you cannot override just hide them, etc.)

I'm not sure if I understand your problem corret but I suggest you construct the objects with a context interface or something. The objects then cann access these context interface if they area allowed to return a value or have to return a special value.

The one creating all these objects can pass the same object and so control the behaviour. This object could then be held static (like a singelton)